# How to install CUDA 7.0 on elementaryOS (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

Trying to install tensorflow with GPU support on my desktop running elementaryOS Freya (which has Ubuntu 14.04 underneath). It's being really difficult.

Going the traditional route and using the package manager, it seems like the instructions are:

1. Download CUDA 7.0 from the [downloads page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-70) (.deb)
2. If you open that .deb file, it opens the software center GUI. If you click 'install' it apparently installs but then I can't find the cuda files on my machine.

   $ which  cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local
   $ whereis  cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local
   cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local:
   $ cd /usr/local
   $ ls
   bin  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
   $ cd bin/
   $ ls
   iptest  iptest2  ipython  ipython2
3. A lot of people recommend this three step process:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install cuda
   ```

but when I try it, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cuda-7-5 cuda-command-line-tools-7-5 cuda-core-7-5 cuda-cublas-7-5
  cuda-cublas-dev-7-5 cuda-cudart-7-5 cuda-cudart-dev-7-5 cuda-cufft-7-5
  cuda-cufft-dev-7-5 cuda-curand-7-5 cuda-curand-dev-7-5 cuda-cusolver-7-5
  cuda-cusolver-dev-7-5 cuda-cusparse-7-5 cuda-cusparse-dev-7-5
  cuda-documentation-7-5 cuda-driver-dev-7-5 cuda-drivers cuda-license-7-5
  cuda-misc-headers-7-5 cuda-npp-7-5 cuda-npp-dev-7-5 cuda-nvrtc-7-5
  cuda-nvrtc-dev-7-5 cuda-runtime-7-5 cuda-samples-7-5 cuda-toolkit-7-5
  cuda-visual-tools-7-5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda cuda-7-5 cuda-command-line-tools-7-5 cuda-core-7-5 cuda-cublas-7-5
  cuda-cublas-dev-7-5 cuda-cudart-7-5 cuda-cudart-dev-7-5 cuda-cufft-7-5
  cuda-cufft-dev-7-5 cuda-curand-7-5 cuda-curand-dev-7-5 cuda-cusolver-7-5
  cuda-cusolver-dev-7-5 cuda-cusparse-7-5 cuda-cusparse-dev-7-5
  cuda-documentation-7-5 cuda-driver-dev-7-5 cuda-drivers cuda-license-7-5
  cuda-misc-headers-7-5 cuda-npp-7-5 cuda-npp-dev-7-5 cuda-nvrtc-7-5
  cuda-nvrtc-dev-7-5 cuda-runtime-7-5 cuda-samples-7-5 cuda-toolkit-7-5
  cuda-visual-tools-7-5
```

Those are all version 7.5. And if I do the same again without the `sudo apt-get update` I get the same result. I need version 7.0 for Tensorflow. As far as I can tell the conversion from 7.0 to 7.5 was just magic.

4. The other option is to install with the runfile, as in [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/erikbern/78ba519b97b440e10640). But when you get to the crucial step, of actually installing, I get [this error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run) because I'm logged in. This can be worked around with the solution that follows that question, except CNTL+ALT+F1 does nothing when I press them, so I can't open the TTY terminals. There doesn't seem to be another way to access TTYs. Either elementaryOS doesn't support those keystrokes or it's trying to be clever with my keyboard, which is an apple keyboard (F10, F11, and F12 control the volume, which elementary seems to get, meaning it might be doing something silly with all the F keys.

Help anywhere in this chain would be very helpful.

Comment: This would appear to be off-topic for [SO], and I've voted to close it. But having said that, there appears to be a metapackage called `cuda-7-5`. Do you think there might be one called `cuda-7-0`? Could you try explicitly installing that if it exists?

Comment: In your proposed set of commands (item 3 in your question) try `sudo apt-get install cuda-7-0`  instead of `sudo apt-get install cuda`.  See [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#package-manager-metas.) and [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/907350/cuda-setup-and-installation/installing-cuda-7-0-but-get-cuda-7-5-/), this is expected behavior.  `sudo apt-get install cuda` installs the *latest version enabled in the repo*

Comment: Thanks guys. sudo apt-get install cuda-7-0 worked. @talonmies do you want me to delete this question?

Comment: @AlexLenail: Either that or add an answer yourself. IMHO, this is effectively an operating system version specific package management question rather than a CUDA programming question and probably a better fit for superuser or askubunutu, but that's just my opinion. What I don't really want is for this question to hang around for years with no answer. So either self-answer it (and accept the answer when you can) or delete it. It is your call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @talonmies points out in the comments, the solution is to `sudo apt-get install cuda-7-0`. The documentation for this is very thin -- I wish I hadn't spent as long debugging this.